# Elasticsearch sub-aggregation with a condition

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-aggregation

I have the database table columns like:

ID | Biz Name | License # | Violations | ...

I need to find out those businesses that have more than 5 violations.

I have the following:

```
{
   "query": {
       "bool": {
         "must": {
            "match": {
              "violations": {
                "query": "MICE DROPPINGS were OBSERVED",
                "operator": "and"
              }
            }
          },
          "must_not": {
            "match": {
              "violations": {
                "query": "NO MICE DROPPINGS were OBSERVED",
                "operator": "and"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    },

    "aggs" : {
          "selected_bizs" :{
                 "terms" : {
                      "field" : "Biz Name.keyword",
                                "min_doc_count": 5,
                                "size" :1000
                           },
                      "aggs": {
                          "top_biz_hits": {
                          "top_hits": {
                              "size": 10
                              }
                          }
                      }
                 }
            }
       }
```

It seems working.

Now I need to find out those businesses that have 5 or more violations(like above), and also have 3 or more license #s.

I am not sure how to further aggregate this.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's assume that your `License #` field is defined just like the `Biz Name` **and has a `.keyword` mapping**.

---

Now, the statement:

> find the businesses that have ... 3 or more license #s

can be rephrased as:

> aggregate by the `business name` under the condition that the number of **distinct values** of the bucketed `license IDs` is **greater or equal to 3**.

With that being said, you can use **the [`cardinality` aggregation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-metrics-cardinality-aggregation.html)** to get distinct License IDs.

Secondly, the mechanism for "aggregating under a condition" is the handy **[`bucket_script` aggregation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-pipeline-bucket-selector-aggregation.html)** which executes a script to determine whether the currently iterated bucket will be retained in the final aggregation.

Leveraging both of these in tandem would mean:

```json
POST your-index/_search
{
  "size": 0, 
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": {
        "match": {
          "violations": {
            "query": "MICE DROPPINGS were OBSERVED",
            "operator": "and"
          }
        }
      },
      "must_not": {
        "match": {
          "violations": {
            "query": "NO MICE DROPPINGS were OBSERVED",
            "operator": "and"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "aggs": {
    "selected_bizs": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "Biz Name.keyword",
        "min_doc_count": 5,
        "size": 1000
      },
      "aggs": {
        "top_biz_hits": {
          "top_hits": {
            "size": 10
          }
        },
        "unique_license_ids": {
          "cardinality": {
            "field": "License #.keyword"
          }
        },
        "must_have_min_3_License #s": {
          "bucket_selector": {
            "buckets_path": {
              "unique_license_ids": "unique_license_ids" 
            },
            "script": "params.unique_license_ids >= 3"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

and that's all there's to it!